# Getting XmlDocument to cooperate between .NET Core and .NET Framework

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, xmldocument

We've recently converted a library to .NET Core 2.0 from .NET 4.5.2. This library has many methods/properties that return type `XmlDocument`.

We also have an application (also in .NET 4.5.2) that referenced the 4.5.2 library and now want to use the Core version instead. This application performs certain tasks on the documents that the referenced library returns.

I assume there is some fundamental difference in how `XmlDocument` is between .NET Core and the framework (this is that part I'm still trying to understand and workaround). But I'm very new to Core and do not quite understand that yet.

Here is some brief code that replicates my issue:
**Core 2.0 library**

```
using System.Xml;

namespace TestCoreXmlDoc
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public static XmlDocument DoAThing()
        {
            XmlDocument libDoc = new XmlDocument();
            libDoc.LoadXml("<root></root>");
            return libDoc;
        }
    }
}
```

**.NET 4.5.2 application**

```
using System.Xml;

namespace ConsoleAppTextXmlDoc
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Error on below line
            XmlDocument appDoc = TestCoreXmlDoc.Class1.DoAThing();
        }
    }
}
```

The specific error I see is: "Reference to type 'XmlDocument' claims it is defined in 'System.Xml.ReaderWriter', but it could not be found".

Seems to have some relation to NuGet, but I'm not sure (we currently don't use NuGet for this application, and would rather keep it that way unless we need to make that change).

Comment: There is no fundamental difference in the *class*, but .NET Core has split the framework up into more modules than the regular .NET Framework (to isolate "old" classes like `XmlDocument`, for example). You *will* need NuGet, to add a reference to [`System.Xml.XmlDocument`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Xml.XmlDocument/).

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert - I think that's a sufficient answer if you want to post it!

Comment: is this a .net core library or a .net standard library? it can only work with .net standard. referencing a .net core dll in a .net (full framework) project isn't supposed to work.

Comment: @MartinUllrich - .NET Core.

Comment: But it looks like I'm swapping over to standard :)